# Heading not in capital letter

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, thesis

I am writing a book and i am using the package fancyhdr. I manage to have the configuration i've been looking for (chapter name in the even page, section name in the odd page ...) but there is one problem; the heading are in capital letter and i don't find a solution to fix it. Here's my code:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

 \fancyfoot[C]{}    
 \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}        
 \fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}        
 \fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\leftmark}      
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `fancyhdr` you can use `\nouppercase` in the header and footer fields.

```
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working! But, what is the aim of blindtext?

Comment: Package `blindtext` provides the command `\blinddocument` which I have used to get some contents for testing and showing the result. It is not needed for your document.